# Is this the correct way to model a relationship between an object which may or may not have another object?

Tags: database-design, schema, relational-theory

I'm creating a database for a department store and the database has two tables: `Items` and `Coupons`. An item, like a TV, can only ever have one coupon. Some items don't have a coupon at a given time. Therefore my schema is:

`Items`: `item_id`, `name`, `price`, `desc`, ...
`Coupons`: `coupon_id`, `item_id`, `rate`, ...

This way, when I query for items, I get a list of all items. If I want only items with a coupon, I can either select all coupons and then individually query for the item to which a coupon belongs, or I can perform a natural join between the two tables and get a list of only items with coupons.

I don't think adding a `coupon_id` column to the `Items` table is correct because then there will be null coupon_ids, which I believe is not optimal.

Is everything I've said above correct? Or would adding the `coupon_id` column to `Items` and having null `coupon_id` be completely acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

I would favor your first arrangement where you have an `Item_Id` FK in the `Coupon` table.

- You will be able to enforce the "One coupon per item rule" through a unique constraint on the `Item_Id` column in your `Coupon` table.
- You will be able to easily allow multiple coupons per item if business decides to change their mind.
- Like you said you can easily select and filter your items vs. coupons relationships
- Putting the `Item_Id` in the `Coupon` table allows you to maintain a history of coupons that were valid for that item which is often useful.

The only potential problem I see is in some ways you are focusing on tying a coupon to a *specific* item on issuance of the coupon.  This only becomes a problem when business decides that they want to hand out "20% off your highest priced item," or "50% off everything in the store on XYZ date" coupons to their most valuable customers.  This can be resolved of course.  I just mentioned it to get you thinking about ways the design might need to change in the future.